# Get the application context in liferay session.js

Tags: liferay

How can i get the name of the application context name in the liferay session .js? This is required because i need to put one sign Out link in the session timed out pop up and once clicked it'll redirect me to the login page of that application. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In session.js you should have available the "themeDisplay" object, which has getPathContext()  method.

Hope it helps!